# VueRouter is not changing routes inside laravel

Tags: laravel-5, vuejs2, vue-router

I am stuck at this point where i can not load my components with view router, I can only load Foo component but when i type the url for Bar i get the "Sorry the page can not be found " from Laravel

```
require('./bootstrap');

window.Vue = require('vue');
import VueRouter from 'vue-router';

 const Foo = { template: '<div>foo</div>' }
 const Boo = { template: '<div>Bar</div>' }

 Vue.use(VueRouter);

const routes = [
 { path: '', component: Foo },
 { path: '/boo', component: Boo }
];


const router = new VueRouter({
  mode   : 'history',
  history: true ,
  routes
});


const app = new Vue({
 router
 }).$mount('#app')
```

What am i doing wrong ?

Comment: One thing - do you use <router-view></router-view> in your app template? The other thing, how are you planning to use vue, vue router and laravel together? Because it seems that you try to mix client side and server side routing.

Comment: Yeah, I do have vue-router in my app, and I am trying to use laravel as my server and vue as my front end, i can only navigate to home route with / but other than that I get the laravel error

Comment: That means you don’t have these routes in Laravel right now, right?

Comment: You have "Bar" as the inner text of your div. Your component and its route is called "Boo", not "Bar".

Answer (score 0):

You have "Bar" as the inner text of your div. Your component and its route is called "Boo", not "Bar".